# Simple easing on bootstrap scrollspy

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, easing, scrollspy

This is pretty simple question I think for those who knows javascript/jquery good. I am pretty new to all this and couldn't make it. I found code that is calculating the offset of navbar that looks like this:

```
var offset = 50;

$('.navbar li a').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$($(this).attr('href'))[0].scrollIntoView();
scrollBy(0, -offset);

});
```

And here is the [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/rjSfP/105/) of what I have so far. As you can see if you click link in navbar it just skips to section. Where in this script to add `easing` so it scroll down a bit smoother?

With original code I found first I had that smooth scroll but with new script is lost. This is the old code:

```
$(function() {
$('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Comment: "Make sure to include the scrolling-nav.js, jquery.easing.min.js, and scrolling-nav.css files." - from your fiddle....

Comment: @nevermind I did, inside html part of fiddle. But i think i just need here some simple line of code to add easing, i just don't know how to add.

Answer (score 4):

**Plavookac** Hi there.
I have set up a working sample here in this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uf8qty75/1/)** for you.
When you place this code in your page, place it below all of you other js script links. or if you put this in a script link, place the link at the end.
I take it that you would already have the jquery link .

Have a look at this code here, you will see the smooth scrolling and the offset.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add scrollspy to <body>   
  $('body').scrollspy({target: "#navbar"}); 

  // Add smooth scrolling on all links inside the navbar
  $("#navbar a").on('click', function(event) {
    // Prevent default anchor click behavior
    event.preventDefault();

    // Store hash
    var hash = this.hash;

    // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
    // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 60
    }, 800, function(){

      // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
      window.location.hash = hash;
    });
  });
});
```

Notice this line of code...  `event.preventDefault();` this is used to prevent that flicker when first clicked to start the scrolling.

This part of the code will handle the **smooth scroll**.

```
// Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
// The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 60
    }, 800, function(){

// Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
    window.location.hash = hash;
});
```

Does this help?