# bootstrap scrollspy with smooth scroll wrong target

Tags: bootstrap-4, smooth-scrolling, scrollspy

I tried to make Scrollspy smooth scroll using bootstrap. This works, but the scroll target is wrong.

You can see my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gdfqtLxh/12/

[>> THIS SCREENSHOT <<](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49PPx.png)

> UPDATE VIDEO : https://youtu.be/pZCc90Dv5kw

If you click on the **second menu**, it will work well, but when you click on the **third menu**, it doesn't go to the right target.

This is my javascript..

```
$("#list-example a[href^='#']").on('click', function(e) {

// prevent default anchor click behavior
  event.preventDefault();

  // store hash
  var hash = this.hash;

  // animate
  $('.scrollspy-example').animate({
    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
  }, 300);

});
```

> UPDATE VIDEO (Added some text) : https://youtu.be/921oDDaSZq0

Comment: I checked out your jsfiddle but everything works correctly (clicking the third button selects the right section). Are you still having an issue with this?

Comment: yes, you can see https://youtu.be/pZCc90Dv5kw

Comment: or https://youtu.be/921oDDaSZq0 (Added some text)

Answer (score 0):

Your jsfiddle works correctly in Firefox but not in Chrome.

I replaced all your js and css links with bootstrap's original links in case they were outdated, and it works in Chrome now.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Check out this jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/h6nc9ro4/

I also took out your javascript code since it's not required.

Comment: Note: although it works, the correct active link isn't getting selected correctly. I'm still looking into that.

Comment: I use JavaScript to make the scroll smooth.. That's the problem.. If I don't add a smooth scroll, it will be normal like yours.

Comment: This answer may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32922813/simple-easing-on-bootstrap-scrollspy?rq=1